# gcloud init on ubuntu 18.04 GCP VM doesnt work properly

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sdk

After I successfully stated to use the xxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com and get the message:

```
You are logged in as: [347619542646-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com].
```

I get the following Warning, making it unable to me to choose a Project. [The Account has proper permissions assigned: "Editor"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuQeV.png)

```
WARNING: Listing available projects failed: HttpError accessing <https://cloudresourcemanager.
googleapis.com/v1/projects?alt=json&filter=lifecycleState%3AACTIVE&pageSize=201>: response: <{
'www-authenticate': 'Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/", error="insufficient_scope", 
scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-pl
atform.read-only https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects https://www.googleapis.
com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly"', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'content-type'
: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Mon, 24 Aug 2020 21:25:23 GMT', 'server': 'ESF',
 'cache-control': 'private', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'x-cont
ent-type-options': 'nosniff', 'server-timing': 'gfet4t7; dur=70', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunke
d', 'status': '403', 'content-length': '138', '-content-encoding': 'gzip'}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
>
Enter project id you would like to use:
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really about permissions, but the request is missing a required oAuth2 scope.

Just run `gcloud init` as the project's owner, instead of complicating things for no reason.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean I should not use the service account but my own account (xxx@gmail.com)?

Comment: I solved this problem and all I had down the road like this:

 1. Stop youre VM, go to details and hit `Edit`
 2. Scroll down and change the `Cloud API access scopes` to `Allow full access to all Cloud APIs` f.e.